# What's the meaning of ですね in here?

Tags: word-choice

I know that ですね is a form of saying *right?* but in this sentence `これビデオですね` what does that means? I understand that means "it's a video" but I don't understand the `ね`. A friend was recording a video and some people thought it was a photo and they posed but then she said it ain't was a photo.

> - *focusing in some friends*
> - *they pose*
> - これ、ビデオですね。
> - ビデオですか？
> - *laughs*

Comment: What is the context/situation?

Comment: A friend where recording a video, and the others thouth it was a photo but then she said "これ、ビデオですね"

Comment: I'm refraining from posting an answer, simply because I can't describe the exact emotion in English. It's kind of a way of saying, "It's a video, you guys," with an emotional edge attached to it, and a mild expectation of a response or acknowledgement.

Comment: In that case I have a feeling it would be the sixth example in my answer below. The ね is softly stating a fact that the friends may not have realised. "I'm taking a video, not a photo."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @l'électeur asked, what is the context?

> - It could mean `This is a Video, isn't it?`
> - It could also mean `This is a video` as if introducing some long lost technology.
> - It could also show some kind of small astonishment like having found a video where they were expecting something else `Oh! A video!`
> - When addressing something you are confident is a video, without wanting to offend another person's interpretation of the object `This, as you may already know, is a video`
> - Realisation that you are being recorded rather than photographed `You are taking a video right?`
> - From the view of the person taking the video `I'm recording!` (implying that a video rather than a photo is being taken - as with the photo/video element of digital cameras and phone camera/video recorders)

The `ね` is either implying a question where agreement is expected (as in the first example).
Implying solid understanding of the subject (That is definitely a video) as in the second example.
Indicating a small amount of astonishment (as in the third example).
Without intending to cause offense at stating an obvious fact (fourth example).
Questioning the state of something and expecting an answer (fifth example).
Softly stating a fact that others may have not been aware of (sixth example).

EDIT to include @Michael and @user224579's comments

Once again, without more background it could mean anyone of these things and/or more.

Comment: `ね` also is a way of softening a statement that you are confident to be correct, but don't want to offend the listener by stating something known or obvious. "as you may already know, this is a video".

Comment: This is a practical joke where people pose in front of a camera thinking it is a photo, but they're actually being recorded on video.

So whoever was posing realized they were being videographed.

Comment: I did mention that it could further be interpreted in other ways. Nevertheless I have included the situations from both comments in my answer.
Michael - That is definitely a way I have used it before.
user224579 - Without the context it is hard to tell, but as I have experienced this firsthand I have edited it into one of the possibilities in my answer.

Comment: This can be used by both men and woman?

Comment: Yes. In this instance there is no gender-specific restrictions. For example; そうですね OR そうですよね both use ね and can be used by either males or females.

Comment: Just to clarify the ``ね`` in all the cases is to emphasize the "It's a video", right?

Comment: ね in most cases seeks agreement. So by saying ビデオですね the person taking the video was seeking agreement that everyone understands it is in fact a video that is being taken not a picture. Hence in your example the ビデオですか？ question, is said in order for the listener to confirm the speaker's statement and thus reach agreement that video is in fact being taken.

Comment: And what could be the response to the　ビデオですか？

Comment: Assuming you mean the reply from the person that said ビデオですね; whilst laughing or after the reply そうだよ・そうだね・そうです or some other equivalent response. Simply a yes will do. Alternately, as you mentioned laughs, there doesn't need to be a response as the laughing indicates acknowledgement. The laughing could possibly seen as the equivalent to (Oh really? How silly of me not to notice).